# I'v installed NetBeans 6.8 on my MacOS X MacBook and the logs say it cannot be run, any ideas?

Tags: netbeans, macos

I've installed NetBeans 6.8 on my MacBook, and the installation results indicated success. However, every single time I attempt to run the application is shuts down. I monitored the process and noticed the following entries in the console that imply the application cannot be found?

> 3/19/10 10:20:20 PM [0x0-0x22022].org.netbeans.ide.baseide.200912041610[22168] /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.8.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans: line 57: dirname: command not found
>
> 3/19/10 10:20:20 PM [0x0-0x22022].org.netbeans.ide.baseide.200912041610[22168] Cannot read cluster file: /../etc/netbeans.clusters
>
> 3/19/10 10:20:20 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[77] ([0x0-0x22022].org.netbeans.ide.baseide.200912041610[22168]) Exited with exit code: 1

I started researching how to set the default JDK for use by NetBeans, and found repeated use of the following command line entry;

> netbeans --jdkhome /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home
>
> -- from http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDKVersionAndMacOS

When I attempt the command line above, I receive "netbeans command not found".

So do I ...

> 1.) Need to create a command called "netbeans" that points to my install location for NetBeans 6.8? If so how do I do that?
> 2.) How do I get to the netbeans.conf file for NetBeans 6.8, does one even exist for it?

It gets even more interesting, the above happens with Eclipse as well. Yippie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the same problem with Eclipse as well, the problem is probably not specific to NetBeans.  I would start by using Disk Utility to repair your hard drive's permissions, then reinstalling those applications.

Comment: Thanks for your input, titaniumdecoy. I did use the Disk Utility, and several issues were handled by the "Repair Permissions" process. I reinstalled NetBeans 6.8, but it did not resolve the issue. If you have additional recommendations, I'd appreciate the opportunity to try them to get NetBeans 6.8 up and running. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Wow, I think I actually have to reinstall the OS. Titaniumdecoy, have you ever had a situation where X11 on Mac OS X 10.6.2 stopped working?

3/20/10 1:32:26 PM [0x0-0x4c04c].org.x.X11[19688] /Applications/Utilities/X11.app/Contents/MacOS/X11: line 3: dirname: command not found

Comment: I've never had that situation, although you could try opening X11.app to see if it will run.  You can also download and reinstall X11 from Apple's website.  I recently had to do the same for Safari when it wouldn't launch.

Answer (score 0):

> Need to create a command called "netbeans" that points to my install location for NetBeans 6.8? If so how do I do that?

Not sure this would solve your problem but you can create a netbeans command by writing on the terminal

```
sudo ln -s /absolute/path/to/netbeans/bin/netbeans /usr/local/bin/netbeans
```

Comment: Hey, Jeduan, thanks for your recommendation. My BASH session said that /usr/local/bin/netbeans does not exist. I'm wondering if the installation really wasn't successful if /usr/local/bin/netbeans is supposed to be setup before the conclusion of the process. Your thoughts?

Comment: Writing that command will do a symlink or alias between your netbeans executable (bin/netbeans) and put it on /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the system console consistently indicated that the executable could not be found did not by itself indicate the need to reinstall the OS. When X11 failed on my MacBook, I then decided to reinstall because X11 was an "out-of-the-box" installation which worked perfectly in the beginning. No indications were found explicitly demonstrating a virus was present, so I began the reinstallation process. Now that the reinstall is done, NetBeans, X11 et al are running perfectly.