# Netbeans fails to start (Command not Found) on MacOSX

Tags: macos, netbeans, osx-leopard

I've installed Netbeans 6.0.1 on Mac OSX 10.5.8 successfully, but when I try start it up it doesn't and these log entries are logged in System.log:

```
Apr  7 19:35:09 henrique-ordines-macbook [0x0-0x9c09c].NetBeans 6.0.1[53785]: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans: line 48: ls: command not found
Apr  7 19:35:09 henrique-ordines-macbook [0x0-0x9c09c].NetBeans 6.0.1[53785]: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans: line 53: dirname: command not found
Apr  7 19:35:09 henrique-ordines-macbook [0x0-0x9c09c].NetBeans 6.0.1[53785]: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans: line 57: dirname: command not found
Apr  7 19:35:09 henrique-ordines-macbook [0x0-0x9c09c].NetBeans 6.0.1[53785]: Cannot read cluster file: /../etc/netbeans.clusters
Apr  7 19:35:09 henrique-ordines-macbook com.apple.launchd[65] ([0x0-0x9c09c].NetBeans 6.0.1[53785]): Exited with exit code: 1
```

I've repaired permissions using Disk Utility, as suggested [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481789/iv-installed-netbeans-6-8-on-my-macos-x-macbook-and-the-logs-say-it-cannot-be-r), but I still get the same error.

If I log in as the Root user I can start it without problems.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [on this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/uh-oh-bash-ls-command-not-found), the "ls command not found" error was happening because my PATH environment variable had been broken somehow. By me in this case, *uhem*, anyway, once you've fixed that variable so that this part `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin` can also be in the PATH variable, Netbeans works again.